# Run-time error '91' (Object variable or With block variable not set)

Tags: vba, excel

I am relatively new to VBA and am trying to put together a msgbox that will give me a specific number from a web scrape, however I keep running into a run-time error '91' and I simply cannot figure out how to fix this. I have searched countless stackoverflow questions, youtube videos and generic google searches, however have not been successful in finding out the error on my own.

Here is the code:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate ("http://brokercheck.finra.org")
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4

'Enter values from the corresponding sheet
'Set some generic typing for ease
Set doc = IE.document

    doc.GetElementbyID("GenericSearch_IndividualSearchText").Value = Worksheets("Master").Range("D203")
    doc.GetElementbyID("GenericSearch_EmploymingFirmSearchText").Value = Worksheets("Master").Range("C203")

    Set elements = doc.getElementsByTagName("button")
    For Each element In elements
    If element.getAttribute("type") = "submit" Then
        element.Click
        Exit For
    End If
    Next element

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4

'find CRD#
    Set crd = doc.getElementsByClassName("summarydisplaycrd")(0).innerText 'here is where the run time error occurs
    MsgBox crd
```

and the HTML I am trying to get the information from:

```
<div class="searchresulttext">
    <div class="bcrow">
        <div class=""> <span class="summarydisplayname">[redacted]</span> <span class="summarydisplaycrd text-nowrap">(CRD# 5944070)</span></div>
```

Comment: Which line does it throw the error on?

Comment: Try iterating through the `crd` collection to see if it actually returns anything. My money is on there being no elements found...

Comment: Yep, do `Set crd = doc.getElementsByClassName("summarydisplaycrd")` and then `MsgBox (crd Is Nothing)`

Comment: @macro Man I had a friend do something similar in java and     `doc.getElementsByClassName("summarydisplaycrd")[0].innerHTML` returned the proper crd number,  so I simply edited it to the above in hopes it would work. I iterated (0) to (13) and did get some text, just no the crd# I am looking for.

Comment: Another possible issue is that the `innerText` returns a string, so you don't assign that using the `Set` keyword.  Just do `crd = doc.getElementsByClassName("summarydisplaycrd")(0).innerText` (or `.innerHTML`

Comment: good spot @DavidZemens

Comment: @DavidZemens I am still getting the 91 error with the above line. It now reads `crd = doc.getElementsByClassName("summarydisplaycrd")(0).innerText` and then `MsgBox crd`

Comment: FYI your element class name shouldbe *summarydisplaycrd text-nowrap* as indicated in your HTML.  Do you get the error with `crd = doc.getElementsByClassName("summarydisplaycrd text-nowrap")(0).innerHtml`?

Comment: @DavidZemens Thanks for that. I tried the *summarydisplaycrd text-nowrap* originally, however was using the truncated version as it worked for my friend in Java. *summarydisplaycrd* is the only version of the class name anywhere in the html - And yes, still getting the error message

Comment: Which button are you intending to press on that page?

Comment: @DavidZemens the one labeled "check" -- source code `<div class="input-group-btn  hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md  PaddingLeft15">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit"> <strong>Check </strong></button>`

Comment: OK, I have an answer, let me finish writing it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reviewing this code and the finra.org site, and have the following observations, which when addressed, should resolve the problem.

[image]

1. The HTML example you provided is simply incorrect, based on the actual HTML that is returned from the "Check" button.

   The actual HTML returned looks like this, and the classname is `"displayname"`, not `"summarydisplaycrd"`:

```xml
<div class="SearchResultItemColor bcrow">
    <div class="searchresulttext">
        <div class="bcsearchresultfirstcol">
                <span class="displayname">[redacted]</span> <span class="displaycrd">(CRD# 123456789)</span>
```

2. Your code exits the `For each element` loop upon finding the *first* "submit" button. This *may not be* the "Check" button (although I can get results either way, you may want to add more logic in the code to ensure the "Check " button is submit.

**UPDATE**

On further review, while I can replicate the Type 91 error, I still don't know why your class name appears different than mine (maybe an IE11 thing, dunno...) in any case, I'm able to resolve that by forcing a longer delay, as in this case the `DoEvents` loop is simply not adequate (sometimes this is the case when data is served dynamically from external functions, the browser is ReadyState=4 and .Busy=True, so the loop doesn't do anything)

I use the WinAPI Sleep function and force a 1 second delay after the "Click" button pressed, looping on condition of `ReadyState = 4` **and** `.Busy=True`.

**NOTE** you will need to modify the classname parameter depending on how it is appearing on your HTML.

```vb
Option Explicit
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Sub finra()
Dim IE As Object
Dim doc As Object, element As Object, elements As Object, crd

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate ("http://brokercheck.finra.org")

Call WaitIE(IE, 1000)

'Enter values from the corresponding sheet
'Set some generic typing for ease
Set doc = IE.document

    doc.GetElementbyID("GenericSearch_IndividualSearchText").Value = "steve"
    doc.GetElementbyID("GenericSearch_EmploymingFirmSearchText").Value = "ed"

    Set elements = doc.getElementsByTagName("button")
    For Each element In elements
    If element.getAttribute("type") = "submit" Then
        If element.innerText = "Check " Then
            element.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
    Next element


Call WaitIE(IE, 1000)

Dim itms As Object
'Set itms = doc.getElementsByClassName("displaycrd")
    crd = doc.getElementsByClassName("displaycrd")(0).innerText 'here is where the run time error occurs
    MsgBox crd
End Sub


Sub WaitIE(IE As Object, Optional time As Long = 250)
Dim i As Long
Do
    Sleep time
    Debug.Print CStr(i) & vbTab & "Ready: " & CStr(IE.ReadyState = 4) & _
                vbCrLf & vbTab & "Busy: " & CStr(IE.Busy)
    i = i + 1
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4 And Not IE.Busy
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting. When I "inspect element" I am being brought to `class="summarydisplayname"` however I tried using the edits you just wrote and sill coming up with the same error in the same place! So frustrating!!

Comment: Hmmm I've inspected source (right-click View Source) in the browser and used view mode as IE 10, IE10 compatibility, IE9, IE8 and I only see "displaycrd" as a class name.

Comment: Yours is still indicating `summarydisplaycrd text-nowrap`, contrary to your previous assertions that it is `summarydisplaycrd` only...

Comment: Right. I have also tried with `summarydisplaycrd text-nowrap' and same issue.   ![other attempt](http://imgur.com/hrZEovM)

Comment: Chrome browser is also showing me only `displaycrd`.  What browser are you using to inspect the HTML?

Comment: Both Chrome and IE 11 give me the same `summarydisplaycrd text-nowrap`

Comment: I don't have IE11 to test this unfortunately.  I am curious if you dump the `doc.DocumentElement.InnerHTML` in to a text file, whether the resulting HTML matches what you see in the View Source.

Comment: Also, try `crd = doc.DocumentElement.getElementsByClassName(...`

Comment: I have the text file for the HTML already to test if it does match (can see the two versions on the screenshot above), which it does. I'm not entirely sure why we are seeing different versions. All that said, the error '91' is being set so not sure why this exact error is being given

Comment: what I'm asking is to explicitly dump the results of the `doc.DocumentElement.InnerHTML` into a text file -- this *may be different* than what you see when using the browser's debug/view source (although I don't know why it would be).

Comment: ah ok, I see what you are saying. Although, I'm not entirely sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: Do you get an error with `Set crd = doc.getElementsByClassName("summarydisplaycrd")`?  DO NOT attempt to get the `(0).innerText` yet. Just assign the collection. I'm curios to see if that fails.

Comment: I did **NOT** get an error message. However, worth noting, I did have to remove `MsgBox crd`

Comment: OK the page hasn't loaded. IDK why I didn't htink about that earlier, but there are some other quirks that looked like more obvious problems to address.

Comment: The `DoEvents` loop is simply not sufficient in this case.

Comment: Awesome! I was able to get it working by adding `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))` and then `crd = doc.getElementsByClassName("summarydisplaycrd text-nowrap")(0).innerText` Note: if I changed the wait time to 1 second, it would give me an error message, however 2 seconds works perfectly fine.

Comment: `Wait` will probably work, but `Sleep` is usually more reliable. Cheers!

Comment: If you are using 64 bits, some problems can occur with the Sleep Sub. So refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41638733/7690982) and replace this part of the code: `Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)`.