# Navigating through websites

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, vba

My code is able to interact with the first webpage it brings up, but then as soon as i navigate away from it, my code gives me a '424' object required error. Here is an example.

EX: go to yahoo.com - search for 'Earth' - click on the Yahoo logo to return to the yahoo homepage

```
Sub InternetPractice()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer

Set ie = New InternetExplorer

ie.Visible = True

ie.navigate "https://www.yahoo.com"

Do While ie.Busy = True Or ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

ie.document.getElementById("uh-search-box").Value = "Earth"
ie.document.getElementById("uh-search-button").Click


Do While ie.Busy = True Or ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

ie.document.getElementById("logo").Click

End Sub
```

Using VBA with the internet is new to me and any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT:

I think you are not giving enough time for ie to load... It is working for me.
So you can try this code that gives more time and try to load 3 times before aborting.

```
Option Explicit
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Sub InternetPractice2()


    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim logo As Object
    Dim n As Long
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer                'Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With IE
        .Silent = True
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "https://www.yahoo.com"
    End With

    WaitIE IE, 5000

    Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document
    HTMLDoc.getElementById("uh-search-box").Value = "Earth"
    HTMLDoc.getElementById("uh-search-button").Click

load:
    WaitIE IE, 10000
    Set logo = HTMLDoc.getElementById("logo")
    If Not logo Is Nothing Then
        logo.Click
    ElseIf logo Is Nothing And n < 4 Then
        n = n + 1
        GoTo load
    End If
    WaitIE IE, 5000

    'Set ie to Nothing
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
Sub WaitIE(IE As Object, Optional time As Long = 250)
'Code from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808000/run-time-error-91-object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-set
Dim i As Long
Do
    Sleep time
    Debug.Print CStr(i) & vbTab & "Ready: " & CStr(IE.READYSTATE = 4) & _
                vbCrLf & vbTab & "Busy: " & CStr(IE.Busy)
    i = i + 1
Loop Until IE.READYSTATE = 4 Or Not IE.Busy
End Sub
```

### Original Answer

Try closing ie in the end of the code and add some delay, because if you step the code with F8, you will see that it works:

```
Sub InternetPractice2()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer

Set ie = New InternetExplorer

ie.Visible = True

ie.navigate "https://www.yahoo.com"

Do While ie.Busy = True Or ie.READYSTATE <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

ie.Document.getElementById("uh-search-box").Value = "Earth"
ie.Document.getElementById("uh-search-button").Click
'Add delay After .Click

Do While ie.Busy = True Or ie.READYSTATE <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
Application.wait Now+Timevalue("00:00:05")

ie.Document.getElementById("logo").Click
'Set ie to Nothing
Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Also close all iexplorer.exe on Windows Task Manager.

Comment: Daniel, I spoke to soon. It works when I go through the code step by step (using F8), but still does not work when I run it normally. Any thoughts?

Comment: Daniel, I appreciate the help. It is definitely a timing thing.