# clicking button on a webpage multiple times in excel vba

Tags: excel, web-scraping, vba

I'm trying to click a button multiple times to get my page loaded fully. Webpage contains a button `SHOW MORE` instead of next page so in html coding behind the button remains same.

I am using the following excel-vba code to hit that button. It actually did click that button, but instead of showing the next results it shows the same result over and over again.

Could you please kindly show me how to make it right. Thanks in advance!

```
    **' VARIABLE DECLARATION
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim county As String
    Dim htmlDoc As Object

    ' CREATING OBJECT
    Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    ' WEBPAGE NAVIGATION
    With IE
    .navigate ("http://www.physiofirst.org.uk/find-physio/search-physio.html")
    .Visible = True
    End With

    ' WAITING FOR WEBPAGE TO LOAD
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readystate = 4

    ' SEARCHING ALL THE THE INDIVIDUAL STATE PHYSICIANS
    Set htmlDoc = IE.document
    Set searchbarvalue = htmlDoc.getelementsbyclassname("form-control mod-text-display")
    i = 0
    For Each classSearch In searchbarvalue
        searchbarvalue(i).Value = "BRISTOL"
    Next classSearch
    While IE.busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    Set buttonclick = htmlDoc.getelementsbyclassname("btn btn-search")
    i = 0
    For Each buttonsearch In buttonclick
        buttonclick(i).Click
    Next buttonsearch
    While IE.busy
        DoEvents
    Wend
    Do
    htmlDoc.getelementbyid("load-more-practice").Click
    While IE.busy
    DoEvents
    Wend
    Loop Until htmlDoc.getelementbyid("load-more-practice").Click = True
End Sub**
```

Comment: You have to Do Until data-page is = "1", because it starts on 2 and go to 1 when is completely loaded. `<a href="" class="link-bordered-load" id="load-more-practice" data-page="1">Show More</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code that  Do Until data-page is = "1", because it starts on 2 and go to 1 when is completely loaded, with all Show More clicked.

```
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Sub test()
Dim IE As Object
Dim county As String
Dim htmlDoc As Object
Dim sURL As String

' CREATING OBJECT
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

sURL = "http://www.physiofirst.org.uk/find-physio/search-physio.html"
' WEBPAGE NAVIGATION
With IE
.navigate (sURL)
.Visible = True
End With

WaitIE IE, 2000

' SEARCHING ALL THE THE INDIVIDUAL STATE PHYSICIANS
Set htmlDoc = IE.document
Set searchbarvalue = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("form-control mod-text-display")
i = 0
For Each classSearch In searchbarvalue
    searchbarvalue(i).Value = "BRISTOL"
Next classSearch

WaitIE IE, 1000

Set buttonclick = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-search")

buttonclick(0).Click
WaitIE IE, 1000
Set ShowMore = htmlDoc.getElementById("load-more-practice")

Do
ShowMore.Click
WaitIE IE, 2000
Loop Until ShowMore.getAttribute("data-page") = 1

'IE.Quit
'Set IE = Nothing
End Sub

Sub WaitIE(IE As Object, Optional time As Long = 250)
'Code from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808000/run-time-error-91-object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-set
Dim i As Long
Do
    Sleep time
    Debug.Print CStr(i) & vbTab & "Ready: " & CStr(IE.readyState = 4) & _
                vbCrLf & vbTab & "Busy: " & CStr(IE.Busy)
    i = i + 1
Loop Until IE.readyState = 4 Or Not IE.Busy
End Sub
```

Comment: danieltakeshi got your point. program just went well. hats off to you dear (Y)

Comment: Set ShowMore = htmlDoc.getElementById("load-more-practice")

everything is perfect but sometimes excel vba stuck at this line and asks for debugging and sometimes it went well. can you please tell what is wrong in here?

Comment: You ie is not loading it completely, try to give more time to load `WaitIE IE, 2000` to `WaitIE IE, 5000`, if it continues, increase the time of wait between Clicks.

Comment: You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182132/navigating-through-websites/47183925#47183925) issue, that was the same as yours. If you step the program with F8, it won't bug.

Comment: yup that was it .... my IE was loading properly ... much appreciated dear ... (Y)