# IE .Click not working properly due to value onchange

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

### Problem

Trying to automate a search on this website http://biblioteca.aneel.gov.br/index.html.

Where the search is made on a hidden tab:

[image: Hidden tab of the search]

- So the hidden tab is named: Legislação

And the html Code:

```
<a name="lk_legis" class="link_abas" id="lk_leg" onclick="move_layer('legislacao', parent.hiddenFrame.layerX);" href="#">

    <span class="text-aba" id="aba_leg">Legislação</span>

</a>
```

- The field to fill is: Todos os campos

And the HTML Code:

```
<td><input name="leg_campo1" tabindex="1" class="inputLegEsq" style="margin-top: 0px;" onkeypress="return validaTecla(1,this,event,5,5613,'','parent.hiddenFrame.modo_busca',0)" onchange="atualizaLeg_campos();" type="text" maxlength="500" value=""></td>
```

- And the Search Button: Busca

And the HTML Code:

```
    <input name="bt_comb" tabindex="20" title="Submeter busca" class="button_busca" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" onclick="return Confere(5613,5,'',parent.hiddenFrame.modo_busca)" type="button" value="Buscar">
    <input name="bt_limpar" tabindex="21" title="Limpar campos" class="button_busca" onclick="Resetar();atribuiLegs();" type="button" value="Limpar">
```

### Atempts to Solve

So I tried to solve with the code below:

```
'Declara função Sleep
#If VBA7 Then
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr) 'For 64 Bit Systems
#Else
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) 'For 32 Bit Systems
#End If
Sub CDE_ANEEL()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim doc As Object, doc1 As Object, doc2 As Object, aba As Object
    Dim el

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.navigate "http://biblioteca.aneel.gov.br/index.html"
    IE.Visible = True
    EsperaIE IE, 2500
    Set doc = IE.document.getElementsbyTagName("frame")(0).contentdocument.body
    Set doc1 = doc.getElementsbyClassName("inputLegEsq")
    Set doc2 = doc.getElementsbyClassName("button_busca")
    Set aba = doc.getElementsbyClassName("text-aba")

    For Each el In aba
        'Debug.Print el.InnerText
        If el.InnerText = "Legislação" Then el.Click
    Next el

    For Each el In doc1
        'Debug.Print el.Name, el.Value
        If el.Name = "leg_campo1" Then
        el.Value = "Conta de Desenvolvimento Energético"
        el.InnerText = "Conta de Desenvolvimento Energético"
        el.Click
        el.Focus
        End If
    Next el

    'Aperta Enter
    Sleep 5000

    'Application.SendKeys ("~"), True



        'Apertar Botão
    For Each el In doc2
        Debug.Print el.Title, el.onclick
        Debug.Print InStr(1, el.onclick, "Confere(5613,5,'',parent.hiddenFrame.modo_busca)")
        If InStr(1, el.onclick, "Confere(5613,5,'',parent.hiddenFrame.modo_busca)") > 0 Then
        el.Click
        Exit For
        End If
    Next el


End Sub

Public Sub EsperaIE(IE As Object, Optional time As Long = 250)
'Código de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808000/run-time-error-91-object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-set
Dim i As Long
Do
    Sleep time
    Debug.Print CStr(i) & vbTab & "Ready: " & CStr(IE.READYSTATE = 4) & _
                vbCrLf & vbTab & "Busy: " & CStr(IE.Busy)
    i = i + 1
Loop Until IE.READYSTATE = 4 Or Not IE.Busy
End Sub
```

However, When the button to search is Clicked. It isn't recognizing as having Data on the Field.

I think it is due to the value onchange function. That is fired only when something is typed and not when the value changes...

I could solve pressing enter with: `Application.SendKeys ("~"), True`.

But I want to make `IE.visible=False`. So how to search it correctly without having to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

p.s.: I am trying to make on VBA, because of another functions. Some people said to use Selenium VBA, however, I never used it.

Comment: Try to opt to XHR instead of IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try something like below

```
If el.Name = "leg_campo1" Then
    el.Value = "Conta de Desenvolvimento Energético"
    Set evnt = doc.ownerDocument.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
    evnt.initEvent "change", True, True
    el.dispatchEvent evnt
End If
```

This comes from the below thread

[How to trigger event in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript)